# Classification tree with timestamp

Tags: r

I'm working with a simple classification tree with only one predictor. The predictor is the timestamp i.e. the number of seconds between the origin and the timestamp. Well, the problem isn't estimate the tree, but ***how can I change the labels split?*** I want in the plot the right format of the timestamp and not the number of seconds. Anyone can help me??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRsrU.png)

Comment: Have you looked into the `pretty` argument for your `plot`? Not sure how it would handle timestamps, but you could try `pretty = 0` or some-such.

Comment: You have to show an example of your dataset (eg. 10 random rows) so we can get an idea of what kind of variables you have. What kind of tree model did you use?

Comment: Yes, I looked pretty but it works with factors and the variable is numeric

Comment: @AntoniosK I'm sorry, but the dataset is confidential. I have a binary response and the time stamp as predictor

Comment: I understand. Maybe create some fake data that match the type of your variables? Can you just multiply the number of seconds with a number (constant) that produces what you want? Try to use the `party` package for your tree model and plot it using `plot(model, type="simple")`.

Comment: @AntoniosK I have found the solution!! I'm going to write the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object tree is a list of 6 elements. If you write nametree$frame$splits you will find a matrix that contains the labels of the splits. I create a function that converts the labels in the right format. The function as.POSIXct played an important role.